# Determining the specificity of css

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm having trouble determining the specificity of this CSS rule. I've read plenty on the matter. What is the specificity of:

```
#sidebar h1, p em, p a:hover{ … }
```

Comment: There are three selectors here,`#sidebar h1`, `p em` and `p a:hover`.  Each selector will have its own specificity, which can be determined.

Comment: I am being asked what the total specificity is. I am given the options 114, 115, 204 and 205. I can't seem to get any of those answers though

Answer (score 3):

There are three selectors here,`#sidebar h1`, `p em` and `p a:hover`.

The specificity values are: 101, 002, 012 respectively.

If you add these up, the total is 115.

However, keep in mind that this value is meaningless since the selectors are applied independently of each other.